# Can I apply a matplotlib plot cycle to multiple subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a company-specific color cycle for my python plots. However, I often make figures with  multiple axes, and I don't want the colors to reappear in the second plot.

I can do this by manually incrementing the plot cycler (see example), but is there an automatic way of applying the plot cycler to the entire figure?

The way I currently do it:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)

ax1 = df.plot(y = "Supply temperature",
                    ax = axes[0])

ax1.plot([x_min, x_max], [20,20],label = "Heating SP")
ax1.plot([x_min, x_max], [24,24],label = "Cooling SP")

# Increment plot cycler three times (once for each plot in ax1)
axes[1].plot([], [])
axes[1].plot([], [])
axes[1].plot([], [])

ax2 = df.plot(y = ["Valve setting"],
                    ax = axes[1])
```

Comment: you can indicate the cycle color directly in the plot command like `color='C0'` for first color, `'C1'` for second color and so on.

Comment: @Stef Thanks, this is definitely a handy override for many cases. Maybe I will switch to hard-coded colors with this approach, if no alternative comes up.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.